# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. TS2722

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

Использую связку `useContext & useReducer` с `typescript`. При попытке использовать `useContext` в child-компоненте идет ошибка `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2722`. Я не указывал, что тип может быть `undefined`.

#### Хроника действий:

Создал `context` в родительском компоненте с типизацией:

```
export const initialState: State = {
    newTask: '',
    tasks: []
}
export const ContextApp = React.createContext<Partial<ContextState>>({});
export const Main: React.FC = () => {

    const [state, changeState] = useReducer<React.Reducer<State, Action>>(todoReducer, initialState);

    const ContextState: ContextState = {
        state,
        changeState
    };

    return (
        <ContextApp.Provider value={ContextState}>
            {/* <div className={styles.mainWrapper}> */}
            <Panel />
            <ListItems />
            {/* </div> */}
        </ContextApp.Provider>
    )
}
```

Тот самый тип `ContextState`:

```
export type ContextState = {
    state: State;
    changeState: Dispatch<Action>
}
```

Место ошибки(чайлд компонент). При попытке использовал `changeState` выходит выше описанная ошибка:

```
const { state, changeState } = useContext(ContextApp);

const removeTask = (taskForRemoving: Task) => {
    //Подсвечивается красным (ошибка) ---->
    changeState({ type: ActionType.Remove, payload: taskForRemoving })
}
```

#### Что я пытался сделать?

Нагуглил пару запросов на stackoverflow. Все, что я нашел, но не подходит под мой случай:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913963/cannot-invoke-an-object-which-is-possibly-undefined-ts2722
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312057/how-to-remove-ts2722-cannot-invoke-an-object-which-is-possibly-undefined-err?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export const ContextApp = React.createContext<ContextState>`

Answer (score 1):

Так как в определении типа контекста используется [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), любое из полей может отсутствовать.

Таким образом, может быть, что в какой-то момент `changeState` будет `undefined`, что приведет к ошибке при попытке выполнить его как функцию.

Для решения нужно либо убрать `Partial` из определения типа

```
React.createContext<ContextState>();
```

Либо при вызове использовать [optional chaining operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

```
changeState?.({ type: ActionType.Remove, payload: taskForRemoving })
```